# How does Google chrome identify that it was not closed properly last time?

Tags: google-chrome

Suppose we are browsing with Google Chrome open and suddenly, if computer is shut down.

Later after computer restarts, if Google Chrome is restarted, how does it identify that it was not shut down properly and allows to open last visited webpages?

Answer (score 0):

Within the folder "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" there is a file called 'Current Session' to my knowledge this holds the information from the session you have open and clears itself when a 'safe' Chrome close is initialized.

If Chrome does not close safely then it does not clear this file and then knows what was open from your previous session.